# What is the nominal mod_wsgi WSGIDaemonProcess configuration for running Tornado WSGIAdapter apps?

Tags: tornado, mod-wsgi

I am using Tornado web framework but one of my deployment environments is mod_wsgi on prefork Apache 2 (weird hosting requirement).

Is `processes=n threads=1` the correct way to set up my `WSGIDaemonProcess` for a `tornado.wsgi.WSGIAdapter`? My own code should be threadsafe however, I am binding a SQLAlchemy Session() to an instance of `tornado.web.RequestHandler` in the handler's `.prepare()` as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47934179/2718295) (I'm obviously not using coroutines in WSGI-mode). I'm also using blocking `tornado.httpclient.HTTPClient` in some request handlers.

Also, does `WSGIDaemonProcess` process fork() comparably to `tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer().start(n)`?

(I am posting this question here since I have no idea how to ask both @Ben Darnell and @Graham Dumpleton at the same time without spamming both tornado and mod_wsgi lists).

Comment: What do you mean by "non-threadsafe code in Tornado"? Are you suggesting Tornado Web framework is itself not thread safe, or that your own code is not thread safe? I know of no concerns over thread safety of Tornado Web framework itself.

Comment: My own code is threadsafe; all globals I use are constant. I've edited the question to reflect more of what I am concerned about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WSGIAdapter` *is* thread-safe, and so is the subset of Tornado that works with it (`RequestHandler.write`, for example, is thread-safe when used with `WSGIAdapter`, but not when used with `IOLoop`). So when running with `WSGIAdapter`, you can configure your WSGI server in the same way you would for any other WSGI framework (typically something like 1 process per CPU core (this is comparable to what you get with `HTTPServer.start(n)`) and 5-10 threads per process depending on how much of your time you spend in I/O).

Note that `tornado.httpclient.HTTPClient` objects are *not* thread-safe, so you'll need to put a lock around it or use a separate object per thread.

Comment: So RequestHandler/HTTPRequest themselves are thread-safe in general? (Do I have to lock instance variables during say: `def prepare(self): self.x = self.request.get_arguments('x')`?). Regarding HTTPClient, if I am invoking and assigning locally in a RequestHandler method (`def get(self): httpclient = HTTPClient(...)...`), I still have to lock or use a threadlocal store?

Comment: RequestHandler instances cannot be shared across threads, but in WSGI that is the usual model. The WSGI server will assign a thread for you and you can access the handler in that thread. For HTTPClient if you are just using local variables then everything will be fine; you only need locking if you are sharing objects across threads.