# sqlalchemy when does an object become "not persistent"

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a function that has a semi-long running session that I use for a bunch of database rows... and at a certain point I want to reload or "refresh" one of the rows to make sure none of the state has changed.  most of the time this code works fine, but every now and then I get this error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Instance '<Event at 0x58cb790>' is not persistent within this Session
```

I've been reading up on state but cannot understand why an object would stop being persistent?  I'm still within a session, so I'm not sure why I would stop being persistent.

Can someone explain what could cause my object to be "not persistent" within the session?  I'm not doing any writing to the object prior to this point.

*db_event* below is the object that is becoming "not persistent"

```
async def event_white_check_mark_handler(
    self: Events, ctx, channel: TextChannel, member: discord.Member, message: Message
):
    """
    This reaction is for completing an event
    """
    session = database_objects.SESSION()
    try:
        message_id = message.id
        db_event = self.get_event(session, message_id)
        if not db_event:
            return
        logger.debug(f"{member.display_name} wants to complete an event {db_event.id}")
        db_guild = await db.get_or_create(
            session, db.Guild, name=channel.guild.name, discord_id=channel.guild.id
        )
        db_member = await db.get_or_create(
            session,
            db.Member,
            name=member.name,
            discord_id=member.id,
            nick=member.display_name,
            guild_id=db_guild.discord_id,
        )
        db_scheduler_config: db.SchedulerConfig = (
            session.query(db.SchedulerConfig)
            .filter(db.SchedulerConfig.guild_id == channel.guild.id)
            .one()
        )
        # reasons to not complete the event
        if len(db_event) == 0:
            await channel.send(
                f"{member.display_name} you cannot complete an event with no one on it!"
            )
        elif (
            db_member.discord_id == db_event.creator_id
            or await db_scheduler_config.check_permission(
                ctx, db_event.event_name, member, db_scheduler_config.MODIFY
            )
        ):
            async with self.EVENT_LOCKS[db_event.id]:
                session.refresh(db_event)                ###########  <---- right here is when I get the error thrown
                db_event.status = const.COMPLETED
                session.commit()
                self.DIRTY_EVENTS.add(db_event.id)

            member_list = ",".join(
                filter(
                    lambda x: x not in const.MEMBER_FIELD_DEFAULT,
                    [str(x.mention) for x in db_event.members],
                )
            )
            await channel.send(f"Congrats on completing a event {member_list}!")
            logger.info(f"Congrats on completing a event {member_list}!")
            # await self.stop_tracking_event(db_event)
            del self.REMINDERS_BY_EVENT_ID[db_event.id]

        else:
            await channel.send(
                f"{member.display_name} you did not create this event and do not have permission to delete the event!"
            )
            logger.warning(f"{member.display_name} you did not create this event!")
    except Exception as _e:
        logger.error(format_exc())
        session.rollback()
    finally:
        database_objects.SESSION.remove()
```

Comment: so if I catch the error, I find that ALL of my objects are no longer in the session.

Comment: db.SESSION.object_session(db_event) if I call this, it should return the session _db_event_ is in... it returns None

Comment: Yes it is default

Comment: I will try and get that for you, I’ve added changed things to just requery the object and that seems to have fixed it

Comment: I can tell you off the top of my head it’s the refresh call into verify state into verify persistent, and then it’s not in the identity map.

Comment: Well that definitely sounds like the problem!!!!  I think I’ll go see if there are other scopes... out and about now... I’ll check when I get home

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am fairly certain that the root cause in this case is a race condition. Using a [scoped session](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/contextual.html) in its default configuration manages scope based on the thread only. Using coroutines on top can mean that 2 or more end up sharing the same session, and in case of `event_white_check_mark_handler` they then race to commit/rollback and to remove the session from the scoped session registry, effectively closing it and expunging all remaining instances from the now-defunct session, making the other coroutines unhappy.

A solution is to not use scoped sessions at all in `event_white_check_mark_handler`, because it fully manages its session's lifetime, and seems to pass the session forward as an argument. If on the other hand there are some paths that use the scoped session `database_objects.SESSION` instead of receiving the session as an argument, define a suitable [`scopefunc`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/contextual.html#sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session.params.scopefunc) when creating the registry:

- https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/contextual.html#using-custom-created-scopes
- [SQLAlchemy+Tornado: How to create a scopefunc for SQLAlchemy's ScopedSession?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674984/sqlalchemytornado-how-to-create-a-scopefunc-for-sqlalchemys-scopedsession)
- [Correct usage of sqlalchemy scoped_session with python asyncio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34369164/correct-usage-of-sqlalchemy-scoped-session-with-python-asyncio)

Comment: Upvoting because this is helpful no matter what. If it works I’ll come back and accept it. Thank you!

Comment: so I could not find anyway to come up with a suitable scopefunc, as nothing in the discord.py library (that I could find) enables me to identify which "request" I'm handling.  That being said, if I just create the session (not using a scoped_session) at the beginning of my callaback for each request and close it at the end of each one... this seems to work fine.  Thank very much for your assistance, I was struggling to understand how scoped_sessions work!

Answer (score 4):

I experienced this issue when retrieving a session from a generator, and try to run the exact same query again from different yielded sessions:

```
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(bind=engine, class_=Session)
    
def get_session() -> Generator:
    with SessionLocal() as session:
        yield session
```

The solution was to use session directly (in my case).
Perhaps in your case I would commit the session, before executing a new query.

```
def get_data():
    with Session(engine) as session:
        statement = select(Company)
        results = session.exec(statement)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i worked with Tornado
I placed a function like so - in the `BaseClass`

```
def __del__(self):
  if self.session:
     self.session.close()
```

Because i didn't want to implement this `__del__` function in any inherit class

The issue that happened, was because that when a class was destroyed (the `__del__` was triggered and closed my connection ) and then brought up again but didn't bring my session with it ( in my `init` class i create it ). so the connection was closed when I tried to re-use it.

My solution was - to move this generaic - high level `__del__` inside every class.